# Global temporary table throwing SQL Integrity constraint exception sometimes when invoking the stored proc

Tags: spring, db2

I'm trying to debug an error at work. It is using a stored procedure (in DB2) with a global temporary table to store and return back results. Consider the following code snippet inside the stored_proc

```
declare global temporary table session.details
(
    row_count   integer not null generated always as identity,
 ...
)
with replace on commit delete rows not logged on rollback delete rows;
```

The stored_proc itself is being called by Spring framework.
The bug is that sometimes (very often actually) when Spring invokes the stored_proc I see errors like

```
[FMWGEN][DB2 JDBC Driver][DB2]INSERT/UPDATE INVALID; INDEX 1 RESTRICTS COLUMNS WITH SAME VALUES; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
[FMWGEN][DB2 JDBC Driver][DB2]INSERT/UPDATE INVALID; INDEX 1 RESTRICTS COLUMNS WITH SAME VALUES
```

Here is the java code snippet invoking this stored_proc

```
SqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("v_input", input)
Map<String, Object> result =  proc.execute(parameterSource);
```

proc is an instance variable

```
private SimpleJdbcCall proc

this.proc =new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
     .withSchemaName("schema")
     .withProcedureName("proc")
     .declareParameters(
       new SqlParameter("v_input", java.sql.Types.INTEGER)
    ).returningResultSet("output", new CustomRowMapper<String>());
```

According to IBM DB2 docs the Global Temporary Table gets destroyed and recreated for every session, but from the sql exception seems like that is not happening? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Database sessions are bound to the connection. Assuming that you followed general guidelines for performance you have a connection-pool. Basically connections are reused and as such the session is never destroyed.

Comment: One would presume that the transaction had been committed (or rolled back) prior to returning the connection to the pool, which, according to the DGTT definition, would have deleted all rows.

Comment: We are using Spring JDBC with weblogic - so I would think the container must be maintaining some kind of connection-pool and must be reusing the sessions. So in situation like these how can we guarantee that the DGTT is always cleared?

Comment: @Raja -- you just need to make sure you commit (or rollback) at appropriate moments.

Comment: @Raja – @mustaccio's comment is correct re: commit/rollback.  You also have the option of simply ensuring that the application creates the DGTT.  You have the `with replace` clause, so if the DGTT already exists it would simply be replaced when the `DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE...` statement is executed again.

Comment: Could you create an answer for that, I'll remove my answer after that.  One thing I wonder is, how would this behave with an auto-commit?